# Weird Behaviour with const_cast

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I know that using `const_cast` is  generally bad idea, but I was playing around with it and I came across a weird behaviour, where:

Two pointers have the same address value, yet when de-referenced, give different data values.

Does anyone have an explanation for this?

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const int M = 10;

    int* MPtr = const_cast<int*>(&M);

    (*MPtr)++;

    std::cout << "MPtr = " << MPtr << "   (*MPtr) = " << (*MPtr) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  &M = " << &M << "         M = " << M << std::endl;
}
```

**Output**

```
MPtr = 0x7fff9b4b6ce0   (*MPtr) = 11
  &M = 0x7fff9b4b6ce0         M = 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, aside from the "it's undefined behaviour" (which it is), the compiler is perfectly fine to use the fact that `M` is a constant, thus won't change, in the evaluation of `cout ... << M << ...`, so can use an instruction that has the immediate value 10, instead of the actual value stored in the memory of `M`. (Of course, the standard will not say how this works, more than "it's undefined", and compilers are able to choose different solutions in different circumstances, etc, etc, so it's entirely possible that you'll get different results if you modify the code, use a different compiler, different version of compiler or the wind is blowing in a different direction).

Part of the tricky bit with "undefined behaviour" is that it includes things that are "perfectly what you may expect" as well as "nearly what you'd expect". The compiler could also decide to start tetris if it discovers this is what you are doing.

And yes, this is very much one of the reasons why you SHOULD NOT use `const_cast`. At the very least NOT on things that were originally `const` - it's OK if you have something along these lines:

```
int x;

void func(const int* p)
{
  ...
  int *q = const_cast<int *>(p);

  *q = 7;
}


...

 func(&x);
```

In this case, `x` is not actually const, it just becomes const when we pass it to `func`. Of course, the compiler may still assume that `x` is not changed in `func`, and thus you could have problems....

Comment: Or, at least, why you should only use `const_cast` on variables which are actually *not* const, but which you have a consted pointer to.

Comment: const_cast is a critical tool, and it exists for a reason.  you just have to know what it is for in order to use it correctly.

Comment: Of course it's there for a reason - language architects (most of the time, at least) don't just add features because they fancy it. However, I have managed to work in C++ for about 7 years, without every needing to use const_cast. A colleague of mine did at one point need to do that - because some function that was declared as `const` needed to modify a member variable, so casting `this` with a const-cast was the only way out (redefining the function would be a much worse solution). So, "shouldn't use" is fine by me.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Very good answer, cheers. Just FYI, there is a keyword that does specifically what your colleague needed: declare the member as "mutable".

Comment: @mga: Yes, that would also be a possible option, but for some reason that wasn't possible - I think because basically "the original class definition can't be changed". It's about 4 years since I worked on that project, and it wasn't me doing that particular work (but I do remember the solution being "const_cast").

Answer (score 5):

The program has undefined bahaviour because you may not change a const object.

From the C++ Standard

> 4 Certain other operations are described in this International
>   Standard as undefined (for example, **the effect of attempting to modify
>   a const object**). [ Note: This International Standard imposes no
>   requirements on the behavior of programs that contain undefined
>   behavior. —end note ]

Comment: In this case, since your `M` is const, the output line doesn't even bother checking what number is stored at its address. It's just a hardcoded "print 10", since you've allowed the compiler to assume that `M` will always be 10.